# C# LINQ Join Object Model Collections and then filter by a property

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, observablecollection

I've been trying to write a LINQ statement that will compare a property from two collections of the same type of object model and produce a third collection of just those where the `OnOff` property is different. I've only been using LINQ for about a week now so I'm still getting used to it.

My understanding is a join will combine two collections and discard any items from them that are exactly the same, so you don't have duplicates.

I got advice to try a `Join` to do this and I'm getting close but I'm not there yet.

My model has string properties for Name, OnOff, Color, etc... I am trying to match models in the collections by name, and then give me a the models where the OnOff property is different.

Written out what I need is, for each `LayerModel` in `SourceDrawingLayers`, look into every `LayerModel` in `TargetDrawingLayers` and see if you find one with a matching `Name`. If you do, check the `OnOff` property. If it is **NOT** equal, `Add` it to the OnOffConflictLayers collection.

I've tried doing this with nested `foreach` statements and `from` x `from` y LINQ queries but I get a ton of duplicates. That's when Join was suggested to me. I just need help taking it home.

so far I have this:

```
            var onOffQuery = from source in SourceDrawingLayers
                         join target in TargetDrawingLayers
                         on source.Name equals target.Name
                         //give me every target where target.OnOff does not equal source.OnOff
                         select new { target.OnOff }; //I don't know if I need this line it's just where I'm stuck at right now.
```

when finished I have to populate a collection with the result:

```
ObservableCollection<LayerModel> q = new ObservableCollection<LayerModel>(onOffQuery);
OnOffConflictLayers = q;
```

I would greatly appreciate help with this (probably super simple) query I am trying to run. Thanks!

Update: See my edit below.

```
private void GetOnOffConflicts()
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        if (TargetDrawingLayers != null && TargetDrawingLayers.Count != 0)
        {
            TargetDrawingLayers.Clear();
        }
        if (OnOffConflictLayers != null && OnOffConflictLayers.Count != 0)
        {
            AllConflictLayers.Clear();
        }

        foreach (TargetDrawingModel targetDrawingModel in TargetDrawings)
        {
            foreach (var result in da.GetDrawingLayers(targetDrawingModel.DrawingPath))
            {
                TargetDrawingLayers.Add(result);
                //everything works fine up to here. My collection is populated correctly.
            }
        }

        var onOffQuery = from source in SourceDrawingLayers
                         from target in TargetDrawingLayers
                         where source.Name == target.Name && source.OnOff != target.OnOff
                         select target;

        ObservableCollection<LayerModel> q = new ObservableCollection<LayerModel>(onOffQuery);
        OnOffConflictLayers = q;
    }
```

Edit: Matt U's answer below is correct. I mistakenly had not set up my target drawing correctly and all of the on/off properties actually were the same, so no wonder my code returned nothing.

Marked Matt's answer as correct.

Comment: glad you solved it. When you say you had mistakenly not set up target drawing correctly, was that because the on/off properties were the same, or was it something else?

Comment: It was because in the drawing (AutoCAD drawing) each layer can be turned on or off and of course I was checking for differences on that setting by layer name (the source drawing has the same layer names as the target drawing). In a moment of sheer genius I hadn't actually changed any to on or off to create a mismatch and then went checking for a mismatch that I never created. Feel dumb, but at least I learned a lot of LINQ techniques in the last two days...

Comment: Haha yeah. Thanks for clarifying, I was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for what's known as a non-equijoin. Instead of a `join`, you'll use two `from` clauses and a `where`.

```c#
var onOffQuery = from source in SourceDrawingLayers
                 from target in TargetDrawingLayers
                 where source.Name == target.Name && source.OnOff != target.OnOff
                 select target;

// onOffQuery should contain the "target" objects where there is a matching Name in source, but OnOff differs.
// You can "select source" if you want the source objects
```

More on non-equijoin and other custom "joins": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-custom-join-operations